# vba - how to calculate average of a column and then autofill the same column

Tags: vba, excel

How do I calculate the average of a range of cells (from H6:lastrow), populate that number in I6 and have that same number autofill all the to the last row (I6:lastrow) using excel VBA? Would love to have these steps automated.

Heres what I have so far (but doesn't work)

```
Sub AverageRates()

With ActiveSheet
    'Determine last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    'Average rate calculation
    Range("I6:I" & lastRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average("H6:H" & lastRow)


End With

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In **'I6'** have the following fomula: `=AVERAGE(H6:<whatever your lastrow is>)`. Now you can just add a reference to the cell in each row (i.e. `=I6`)

Answer (score 0):

Code would be like bellow.

```
Sub AverageRates()

With ActiveSheet
    'Determine last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myAvg As Double
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    'Average rate calculation
    myAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("H6:H" & lastRow))
    Range("I6:I" & lastRow).Value = myAvg


End With

End Sub
```